# iOS rich push notification carousel

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I have been trying to implement a rich push notification in iOS displaying a carousel like in this GIF:

[image]

I am receiving the right payload from the server and parsing it, but I cannot find any information regarding this.

I have tried to use `UNMutableNotificationContent`'s `attachments` var by giving it an array of multiple `UNNotificationAttachment` but it only displays the first one in the array although apple are saying:

> Use this property to include images, movies, and audio files with your notification’s content. The system displays attached content along with the notification. You can also display attachments from your own custom notification interfaces.
>   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unmutablenotificationcontent/1649857-attachments#see-also

Isn't this an iOS built in option?
How do I achieve this?

Thanks :)

Comment: Hi I have implemented it. For this you can use https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel library along with Notification Content Extension.If you need further help, let me know.